# Is it possible to declare a global varaible and initialize it in a function? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, global-variables

```
public Tiles[,] tiles;
```

Is a global variable, an array, I dare say, the size of which is yet to be discovered. That's why I wish to initialize it inside a function. Alas, after the function is done, so is the variable. How doth one fix that?

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote something like this:

```
public void Init()
{
    tiles = new Tiles[2, 5];
}
```

The instantiated array *still exists*. Because it was stored in the `tiles` variable, which is in the class scope, it's lifetime is that of the object. Thus, you have nothing to worry about. Subsequently accessing the `tiles` field (should have been a property...) will use the object created in `Init`.

As an aside, that variable is *not* global, it is scoped to the class. Aside from statics, there is no such thing as a "global" variable in C# (and even static members are still scoped to their class, which does have a global instance).

**Note**

Jon Skeet's answer indicates excellent practice for initializing variables, among other things. I am primarily trying to address the misunderstanding of variable scope/lifetime in this answer.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, I just redefined it inside the function and did not see it. How very stupid of me. Thank you, good man!!

Comment: Why bother assigning in the method? Why not just make the method return the array?

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with you, but the original question asked about initialization within a method. Even doing a return value, it would still be assigned from some *other* method, which still runs into the OPs misunderstanding (unless the method was `static` so it could be used as a member initializer of course).

Comment: Well, it's not clear whether the OP really needs it to be initialized *in* a method, or just "via a method call of some description" (rather than just a single array creation expression). I would definitely favour the approach in my answer, as aside from anything else it allows the field to be readonly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, but it doesn't answer the question: "Alas, after the function is done, so is the variable. How doth one fix that?" which clearly indicates the misunderstanding of variable scope/lifetime. Obviously the OP has some bad practices to be corrected, but thats not what he was asking about.

Comment: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree. I was answering what I believe the OP's bigger task was, rather than the specific way they *expected* to solve it. Hopefully both answers have value.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want:

```
private readonly Tile[,] tiles = InitializeTileArray();

...

private static readonly Tile[,] InitializeTileArray()
{
    Tile[,] array = ...;
    // Whatever you want here
    return array;
}
```

Note that the method has to be static - you can't call an instance method from a field initializer. If you need to do that, you need to put the call into your constructor instead.

Note that I've made the field itself private - and readonly, which may not be appropriate for you. I would recommend *always* (or at least nearly always) using private fields - you can expose the data via properties and indexers.